# delete folder /usr/lib/systemd/system which consequence now

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, ubuntu-18.04, iusr

last time i delete the folder system in /usr/lib/systemd/system.I don't know how, but how  important is the folder system for the ubuntu server 18.04 ?
What consequences should I expect?

kind regards,

blackbeard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this possibly destructive thing on a test system and see what happens. Either a host created for this purpose, or something with a known recovery plan.

A reason for uncertainty here would be that Fedora and EL try very hard to move all the things to `/usr`. On CentOS 7, `/usr/lib/systemd/system` definitely contains system units, and removing all of them would cause the system to not function.

Per [Ubuntu's man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/systemd.unit.5.html), they have not done it quite the same and have `/lib/systemd/system`.  Why exactly `/usr/lib/systemd/system` exists on Ubuntu I don't know. Look at whether its contents are a symlink to the actual location, or perhaps a couple misplaced units that are not packaged to Ubuntu's conventions.

On a system with package management, ideally `/usr` and `/lib` are only managed by installing and removing packages, with no need to directly deal with files. systemd's search paths support this very well, for example `/etc/systemd/system/` is a good place for local custom units and overrides.

Answer (score 1):

The folder `/lib/systemd/system` contains all configuration files for **systemd**. If you deleted the content of this directory, your system might never boot again.

The folder `/usr/lib/systemd/system` might be a symbolic link for `/lib/systemd/system`. If it wasn't everything should be alright, since it is not on **systemd**'s search path. The question is why was there a `/usr/lib/systemd/system` in the first place.

Comment: i dont know, maybe default installation from my ubuntu headless server 18.04 .
You mean the folder /usr/lib/systemd/system is unimportant. I understand from wiki the systemd for user unit  should be us for session service like delete all temporary file after log out  from server. 
Im using only lib/systemd/system and etc/systemd/system.

Comment: `/usr/lib/systemd/system` is not on the search path, but `/usr/lib/systemd/user`, where user units are stored, is!

Comment: What you mean? Is the folder now important?

Comment: `/usr/lib/systemd/user` contains user units and is important, `/usr/lib/systemd/system` does not exist or serve a purpose on a Debianoid.

Answer (score 0):

I found my Problem, i created my own system file in usr/lib/systemd/System. Thanks everbody.